# Android Studio y firebase para la gestión de usuarios

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

resumo brevemente ya que estoy haciendo una app en kotlin con android studio y usando Firebase como gestor de bases de datos, es una aplicación en la que se suben anuncios comerciales a un recyclerview, mi consulta es que me gustaría que en la activity que tengo llamada como mis anuncios, les salga los anuncios que ha subido cada persona cada vez que me loguee y no a todos los usuarios, en resumen necesito saber como asociar una activity a un usuario en especifico y que no le salga lo mismo a todos los usuarios. Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

lo que puedes hacer es que con los identificadores de cada usuario, le agregues un dato extra. por ejemplo:

Usuarios - Id = Maria - Dato - MostrarAnuncio O NoMostrarAnuncio

y de acuerdo al dato le muestras el anuncio o no.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

ya que no traes código, te comparto esta documentación